# Error in node.js/express app: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a problem with setting up a Node.js application with Express for routing and MongoDB (Mongolab) for the database. I've been looking around & found a lot of other users with the same problem, but couldn't find a solution for the problem yet.. Hope that someone can help.

The error I keep getting is `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

I get the error after a `POST /login` request.
I've tried to use `res.end();`, `res.redirect('/users/index');` and to return the render.. But no success yet..

Here the most important code:

**Server.js**

```
  /* LOAD ALL DEPENDENCIES
    ----------------------------------------- */
    const express = require('express');
    const path = require('path');
    const request = require('request');
    const session = require('express-session');
    const compression = require('compression');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const app = express();

    /* MONGODB CONFIGURATION
    ----------------------------------------- */
    const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
    require('dotenv').config();
    const dbConfig = process.env.MONGODB_URI;

    MongoClient.connect(dbConfig, (err, database) => {
      if (err) return console.log(err)
      db = database
    });

    /* SESSIONS CONFIGURATION
    ----------------------------------------- */
    app.use(session({
        secret: "JA1d82JHYF9?nsdfDF635MuHe#ksd",
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: true
    }));

    /* SET PORT FOR HEROKU
    ----------------------------------------- */
    const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
    const host = process.env.HOST ||'0.0.0.0';

    // Rest of the code ..

    app.use('/users', usersRouter);
    // Router is loaded earlier

    /* START THE NPM SERVER
    ----------------------------------------- */
    app.listen(port, host, function() {
        console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`);
    });
```

**users.js (route)**

```
/* LOAD ALL DEPENDENCIES
----------------------------------------- */
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const passwordHash = require('password-hash');

/* INDEX ROUTE
----------------------------------------- */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  if (req.session.login) {
    res.render('users/index');
  } else {
    res.redirect('/users/login');
  }
});

router.get('/login', function(req, res) {
  res.render('users/login');
});

router.post('/login', function(req, res) {
  const loginName = req.body.username;
  const loginPassword = req.body.password;
  db.collection('users').find().toArray(function(err, results) {
    results.map(function(user) {
      if (user['username'] === loginName) {
        const pwCheck = passwordHash.verify(loginPassword, user['password']);
        if(pwCheck === true) {
          req.session.login = true;
          req.session.username = user['username'];
          res.render('users/index');
        } else {
          res.redirect('/users/')
        }
      }
    })
  });
});
```

**Full error**

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:356:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/Users/camillesebastien/Documents/Programming/Mongo App/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:725:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/camillesebastien/Documents/Programming/Mongo App/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
    at done (/Users/camillesebastien/Documents/Programming/Mongo App/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:962:10)
    at tryHandleCache (/Users/camillesebastien/Documents/Programming/Mongo App/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:208:10)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/Users/camillesebastien/Documents/Programming/Mongo App/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:412:10)
    at View.render (/Users/camillesebastien/Documents/Programming/Mongo App/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:128:8)
    at tryRender (/Users/camillesebastien/Documents/Programming/Mongo App/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
    at EventEmitter.render (/Users/camillesebastien/Documents/Programming/Mongo App/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (/Users/camillesebastien/Documents/Programming/Mongo App/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:966:7)
```

**My question**

What does this error mean exactly, what is going wrong? And how could I fix this in this situation?

I'm building in Node.JS with Express as router and mongoDB as database. Could it be that it has something to do with that?

I've checked a lot of similar issues on Stackoverflow, but couldn't solve my issue yet ..

Hope someone can help me, thanks in advance!

**Just came up a thought:**

Could the problem be that I'm testing on localhost, while the mongodb (mongolab) is set on Heroku?

Comment: It would help to know WHEN you get this error. Do you get it when you request `GET /`? What about `GET /login`? `POST /login`?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that. The error occurs at the ```POST /login``` request. The index page (```res.render('users/index');```) is rendered, but the console gives an error. The session seems to work fine, and rendering also happens, but still get the message

Comment: You probably have multiple users with the same username, so when you find the one with the wrong password, it sends a response, but then when you fine one with the right password, it sends another response. You can only send 1 response, otherwise you are trying to send headers after they had already been sent.

Comment: @JoeLissner thanks, there are indeed two users with the same username, didn't think about it yet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that for each result value returned by your DB lookup that matches on password and username you're calling `res.render()`. You can only call `res.render()` one time per request. So in theory this will work if only 1 user is returned and their password matches but if the same user exists multiple times and has the same password you're going to make calls to `res.render()` after it was already sent once.

My suggestion would be to iterate through the list of returned users and then break out after the first time it matches.

Comment: Thanks, had 2 users with the same name in the DB, so that caused the problem. Thanks for helping!